# searching using grep

Tags: grep

hi how do you search for a specific field in a list using grep? For example in a file myfile.txt I need to search for the word apple. Thanks,

```
banana   nut      mango    raisin
plum     peach    cherry   orange
pear     grape    pomelo   apple
papaya   kiwi     avocado  strawberry
```

Comment: it is unclear what exact output you expect. Doesn't `grep apple myfile.txt` work for you?

Comment: yes i can definitely use that, but is there other way where you look for the word via fields?i have a problem that is quite similar to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it depends what exactly you want as output.

'grep -w apple myfile.txt' would be a good start

which results in 'pear     grape    pomelo   apple'

If you just want to search the 4th column for a specific word, you could first use awk to print only the 4th column, and then grep the result

awk '{print $4}' < myfile.txt | grep -w apple
which results in just 'apple'

Comment: what if i wanted to get only the 1st and 3rd column of the 2nd and 4th line? like for example i wanted to get plum papaya cherry avocado?

Answer (score 0):

```
cat myfile.txt | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f4 | grep 'apple'
```